# Process ended with exit code 3 while executing python code

Tags: python, pip, windows-7, 32-bit, thonny

I installed Python 3.8.10 successfully with libraries but when i ran a sample Matplotlib code i am getting this exit code error and no output is coming . My path is correct , my installation is correct . I cannot seem to find the root cause of this error. I have also installed pip.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot([1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 4, 9, 16])
plt.axis([0, 6, 0, 20])
plt.show()
```

Output

```
Process ended with exit code 3.
```

I tried reinstalling Python and Thonny . Thonny and wing are two IDEs i am using as my system is of 32 bit.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of the code or error message. Instead, include the actual code/message into the post directly. This will help 1.) other users with a similar problem to find this question more easily and 2.) reproducing the problem you have.

Comment: @ErikFubel Noted and Corrected